# Show that $a^2 \not\equiv b^2 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given that: $p$ is an odd prime, $a\geq 1,b \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$, and that $a \not\equiv b \pmod p$, show that $a^2 \not\equiv b^2 \pmod p$

Based on the second condition, I know that $a + b < p$ is true, which I think should be helpful, but I'm not sure how to use this.

I also tried to use the fact that $p = 2k + 1$, but again, I didn't find any luck with this.

I'm very new with congruences, so I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I added the "elementary-number-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p\mid a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, then $p\mid a+b$ or $p\mid a-b$ because it is prime. Now as you correctly noted $a+b\lt p$, so $p$ cannot divide $a+b$, therefore $p\mid a-b$; in other words $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$.

Comment: More precisely (or pedantically) $0<a+b<p$ so  $p\not |\,(a+b)$.....+1

Answer (score 4):

If

$a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p \tag 1$

then

$a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0 \mod p, \tag 2$

or

$(a + b)(a - b) \equiv a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0 \mod p; \tag 3$

since

$1 \le a, b \le \dfrac{p - 1}{2}, \tag 4$

we have

$2 \le a + b \le 2\dfrac{p - 1}{2} = p - 1; \tag 5$

it follows that

$a + b \not \equiv 0 \mod p, \tag 6$

and hence that $a + b$ is invertible modulo $p$, since

$\Bbb Z_p = \Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z \tag 7$

forms a field, and $p$ is odd, so $2 \not \equiv 0 \mod p$; from this we conclude that

$a - b \equiv 0 \mod p, \tag 8$

or

$a \equiv b \mod p,  \tag 9$

contrary to the hypothesis

$a \not \equiv b \mod p; \tag{10}$

therefore,

$a^2 \not \equiv b^2 \mod p, \tag{11}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: QED= quod erat demonstratum= which was to be demonstrated.... I am curious about what $OE\Delta$ abbreviates. I've never seen it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:  it's the abbreviation for $\omicron \pi \epsilon \rho \; \epsilon \delta \alpha \iota \; \delta \epsilon \xi \epsilon \iota$, Greek for our oft-appearing Latin "QED".  I got tired of writing *that* all the time, so . . .  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and saying $a^2 \not\equiv b^2 (mod p)$ is the same as saying, $(a-b)(a+b) \not\equiv 0 (mod p)$

You do have from your conditions that $a-b \not\equiv 0 (mod p)$ and since $a+b<p$ then ofcourse $a+b \not\equiv 0 (mod p)$ and $p$ is a prime so now you have that, $a^2 \not\equiv b^2 (mod p)$